# Why does the destructor delete my original binary search tree?

Tags: c++, templates, binary-search-tree, destructor, deep-copy

So I have a project where I have to create a test mode for the user check my copy constructor and destructor for a binary search tree. I do this by passing a binary search tree by value to a function like `testAdds` which internally calls the copy constructor and after the function returns it implicitly calls the destructor thus making sure both of them work. The problem I have is that when the destructor is invoked after function return it ends up deleting my original binary search tree instead. I have no idea why this happens even though I pass it by value and not by reference. Can someone please help me understand why this happens and how to fix it? Any and all help is appreciated!
Here's my code:

`//Executive is the class where I call the test methods (in switch case 6)`

```
#include<fstream>
#include "Executive.h"

Executive::Executive(char* filename) : choice(0), cont(true)
{

    copycheck = false;
    file = filename;
    in.open(file);
    string line;
    while(getline(in, line))
    {
        string a;
        string j;
        string p;
        int i=0;
        for(char&c : line)
        {
            if(c==',') i++;
            else if(c==' ') continue;
            else if(i==0) a += c;
            else if(i==1) p += c;
            else if(i==2) j += c; 
        }
        Pokemon p1(a, stoi(p), j);
        if(!bst.add(p1))
        {
            cout<<"Could not add "<<a<<endl;
        }
    }

}

ofstream out;
void write(Pokemon& p)
{
    out<<p.getAname()<<","<<p.getPokenum()<<","<<p.getJname()<<endl;
}


void Executive::run()
{
    try
    {
        while(cont)
        {
            cout<<"What do you want to do with the Pokedex?"<<endl;
            cout<<"1) Search"<<endl;
            cout<<"2) Save"<<endl;
            cout<<"3) Copy"<<endl;
            cout<<"4) Add"<<endl;
            cout<<"5) Remove"<<endl;
            cout<<"6) Test"<<endl;
            cout<<"7) Quit"<<endl;

            cin>>choice;
            while(choice<1 || choice>7)
            {
                cout<<"Invalid choice. Try again"<<endl;
                cin>>choice;
            }

            switch(choice)
            {
                case 1:
                {
                    string name;
                    cout<<"\nEnter the Pokemon's American name: ";
                    cin>>name;

                    if(bst.contains(name))
                    {
                        Pokemon temp = bst.getEntry(name);
                        cout<<"Japanese Name: "<<temp.getJname()<<endl;
                        cout<<"Pokedex Number: "<<temp.getPokenum()<<'\n'<<endl;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cout<<name<<" is not in the pokedex\n"<<endl;
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case 2:
                {
                    string outfile;
                    string order;
                    if(copycheck)
                    {
                        cout<<"\nWhich pokedex do you want to save?"<<endl;
                        cout<<"1) Original"<<endl;
                        cout<<"2) Copy"<<endl;
                        cin>>choice;
                        while(choice<1 || choice>2)
                        {
                            cout<<"Invalid choice. Try again"<<endl;
                            cin>>choice;
                        }
                    }
                    else choice=1;
                    cout<<"Enter name for output file: ";
                    cin>>outfile;
                    out.open(outfile);
                    cout<<"Enter order of traversal:"<<endl;
                    cout<<"1) pre"<<endl;
                    cout<<"2) in"<<endl;
                    cout<<"3) post"<<endl;
                    int ochoice;
                    cin>>ochoice;
                    while(ochoice<1 || ochoice>3)
                    {
                        cout<<"Invalid choice. Try again"<<endl;
                        cin>>ochoice;
                    }
                    if(ochoice==1)
                    {
                        if(choice==1) bst.preorderTraverse(write);
                        else bstcopy.inorderTraverse(write);
                    }
                    else if(ochoice==2)
                    {
                        if(choice==1) bst.inorderTraverse(write);
                        else bstcopy.inorderTraverse(write);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(choice==1) bst.postorderTraverse(write);
                        else bstcopy.postorderTraverse(write);
                    }
                    out.close();
                    cout<<"An output file with the name "<<outfile<<" has been created!\n"<<endl;
                    break;
                }
                case 3:
                {
                    bstcopy = bst;
                    copycheck = true;
                    cout<<"\nA copy of the pokedex has been created for editing\n"<<endl;
                    break;
                }
                case 4:
                {
                    if(copycheck)
                    {
                        string a, j;
                        int n;
                        cout<<"\nEnter pokemon's American name: ";
                        cin>>a;
                        a[0] = toupper(a[0]);
                        for(int i=1; i<a.length(); i++)
                        {
                            a[i] = tolower(a[i]);
                        }
                        cout<<"Enter pokemon's Japanese name: ";
                        cin>>j;
                        j[0] = toupper(j[0]);
                        for(int i=1; i<j.length(); i++)
                        {
                            j[i] = tolower(j[i]);
                        }
                        cout<<"Enter pokedex number: ";
                        cin>>n;
                        Pokemon p1(a, n, j);
                        if(!bstcopy.add(p1))
                        {
                            cout<<"Could not add "<<a<<'\n'<<endl;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            cout<<a<<" has been successfully added to the pokedex\n"<<endl;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cout<<"\nYou need to create a copy before editing the pokedex!\n"<<endl;
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case 5:
                {
                    if(copycheck)
                    {
                        string a;
                        cout<<"\nEnter pokemon's American name: ";
                        cin>>a;
                        if(bstcopy.remove(a))
                        {
                            cout<<a<<" was successfully removed from the pokedex\n"<<endl;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            cout<<a<<" is not in the pokedex!\n"<<endl;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cout<<"\nYou need to create a copy before editing the pokedex!\n"<<endl;
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case 6:
                {
                    cout<<"\nWhich test would you like to run?"<<endl;
                    cout<<"1) Test adding to a deep copy"<<endl;
                    cout<<"2) Test removing from a deep copy"<<endl;
                    cout<<"3) Test writing to file from a deep copy"<<endl;
                    cin>>choice;
                    while(choice<1 || choice>3)
                    {
                        cout<<"Invalid choice. Try again"<<endl;
                        cin>>choice;
                    }
                    if(choice == 1) t.testAdds(bst);
                    else if(choice == 2) t.testRemoves(bst);
                    else t.testWriteToFile(bst);
                    cout<<endl;
                    break;
                }
                default:
                    cont = false;
            }

        }
        cout<<"\nThanks for using the Pokedex!\n"<<endl;
    }
    catch(NotFoundException& e)
    {
        cout<<e.what()<<endl;
    }
}
```

`//Test is the class where the test methods are defined`

```
#include "Test.h"

ofstream fout;

void writetofile(Pokemon& p)
{
    fout<<p.getAname()<<","<<p.getPokenum()<<","<<p.getJname()<<endl;
}

void display(Pokemon& p)
{
    cout<<p.getAname()<<","<<p.getPokenum()<<","<<p.getJname()<<endl;
}

void Test::testAdds(BinarySearchTree<Pokemon, string> bstc)
{
    string a, j;
    int n;
    cout<<"Enter pokemon's American name: ";
    cin>>a;
    a[0] = toupper(a[0]);
    for(int i=1; i<a.length(); i++)
    {
        a[i] = tolower(a[i]);
    }
    cout<<"Enter pokemon's Japanese name: ";
    cin>>j;
    j[0] = toupper(j[0]);
    for(int i=1; i<j.length(); i++)
    {
        j[i] = tolower(j[i]);
    }
    cout<<"Enter pokedex number: ";
    cin>>n;
    Pokemon p1(a, n, j);
    if(!bstc.add(p1))
    {
        cout<<"Could not add "<<a<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        bstc.inorderTraverse(display);
    }
    //bst.~BinarySearchTree();
}

void Test::testRemoves(BinarySearchTree<Pokemon, string> bstc)
{
    string a;
    cout<<"Enter pokemon's American name: ";
    cin>>a;
    if(bstc.remove(a))
    {
        bstc.inorderTraverse(display);
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<a<<" is not in the pokedex!"<<endl;
    }
    //bst.~BinarySearchTree();
}

void Test::testWriteToFile(BinarySearchTree<Pokemon, string> bstc)
{
    string outfile;
    cout<<"Enter name for output file: ";
    cin>>outfile;
    fout.open(outfile);
    bstc.inorderTraverse(writetofile);
    fout.close();
    cout<<"An output file with the name "<<outfile<<" has been created!"<<endl;
    //bst.~BinarySearchTree();
}
```

`//Here's my Binary Search Tree file. I implement the copy constructor using a private recursive function called "copy" and overlaoding the = operator`

```
//  Subsetted from:
//  Created by Frank M. Carrano and Tim Henry.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 __Pearson Education__. All rights reserved.

/** @file BinarySearchTree.cpp */
#include <iostream>

#include "BinarySearchTree.h" 

// PRIVATE HELPER METHODS - IMPLEMENT THESE

template<typename ItemType, typename KeyType>
void BinarySearchTree<ItemType, KeyType>::destroyTree(BinaryNode<ItemType>* subTreePtr)
{
    if(subTreePtr != nullptr)
    {
        if(subTreePtr->getLeftChildPtr() != nullptr)
        {
            destroyTree(subTreePtr->getLeftChildPtr());
        }
        if(subTreePtr->getRightChildPtr() != nullptr)
        {
            destroyTree(subTreePtr->getRightChildPtr());
        }
        delete subTreePtr;
    }
}

template<typename ItemType, typename KeyType>
BinaryNode<ItemType>* BinarySearchTree<ItemType,KeyType>::insertInorder(BinaryNode<ItemType>* subTreePtr, BinaryNode<ItemType>* newNodePtr)
{
    if(newNodePtr->getItem() < subTreePtr->getItem())
    {
        if(subTreePtr->getLeftChildPtr() == nullptr)
        {
            subTreePtr->setLeftChildPtr(newNodePtr);
            return nullptr;
        }
        else
        {
            return insertInorder(subTreePtr->getLeftChildPtr(), newNodePtr);
        }
    }
    if(newNodePtr->getItem() > subTreePtr->getItem())
    {
        if(subTreePtr->getRightChildPtr() == nullptr)
        {
            subTreePtr->setRightChildPtr(newNodePtr);
            return nullptr;
        }
        else
        {
            return insertInorder(subTreePtr->getRightChildPtr(), newNodePtr);
        }
    }
    return newNodePtr;
}

template<typename ItemType, typename KeyType>
BinaryNode<ItemType>* BinarySearchTree<ItemType, KeyType>::findNode(BinaryNode<ItemType>* subTreePtr, const KeyType& target) const
{
    if(subTreePtr != nullptr)
    {
        if(subTreePtr->getItem() > target)
        {
            return findNode(subTreePtr->getLeftChildPtr(), target);
        }
        if(subTreePtr->getItem() < target)
        {
            return findNode(subTreePtr->getRightChildPtr(), target);
        }
        return subTreePtr;
    }
    return nullptr;
}

template<typename ItemType, typename KeyType>
BinaryNode<ItemType>* BinarySearchTree<ItemType, KeyType>::recRemove(BinaryNode<ItemType>* root, ItemType& itemkey)
{
    if(root == nullptr)
    {
        return nullptr;
    }
    else if(root->getItem()>itemkey)
    {
        root->setLeftChildPtr(recRemove(root->getLeftChildPtr(), itemkey));
    }
    else if(root->getItem()<itemkey)
    {
        root->setRightChildPtr(recRemove(root->getRightChildPtr(), itemkey));
    }
    else
    {
        if(root->isLeaf())
        {
            delete root;
        }
        else if(root->getLeftChildPtr() == nullptr)
        {
            BinaryNode<ItemType>* temp = root;
            root = root->getRightChildPtr();
            delete temp;
        }
        else if(root->getRightChildPtr() == nullptr)
        {
            BinaryNode<ItemType>* temp = root;
            root = root->getLeftChildPtr();
            delete temp;
        }
        else
        {
            BinaryNode<ItemType>* b = greatest(root->getLeftChildPtr());
            ItemType item = b->getItem();
            root->setItem(item);
            root->setLeftChildPtr(recRemove(root->getLeftChildPtr(), item));
        }
    }
    return root;
}

template<typename ItemType, typename KeyType>
void BinarySearchTree<ItemType, KeyType>::recPre(void visit(ItemType&), BinaryNode<ItemType>* subTreePtr) const
{
    if(subTreePtr != nullptr)
    {
        ItemType temp = subTreePtr->getItem();
        visit(temp);
        recPre(visit, subTreePtr->getLeftChildPtr());
        recPre(visit, subTreePtr->getRightChildPtr());
    }
}

template<typename ItemType, typename KeyType>
void BinarySearchTree<ItemType, KeyType>::recIn(void visit(ItemType&), BinaryNode<ItemType>* subTreePtr) const
{
    if(subTreePtr != nullptr)
    {
        recIn(visit, subTreePtr->getLeftChildPtr());
        ItemType temp = subTreePtr->getItem();
        visit(temp);
        recIn(visit, subTreePtr->getRightChildPtr());
    }
}

template<typename ItemType, typename KeyType>
void BinarySearchTree<ItemType, KeyType>::recPost(void visit(ItemType&), BinaryNode<ItemType>* subTreePtr) const
{
    if(subTreePtr != nullptr)
    {
        recPost(visit, subTreePtr->getLeftChildPtr());
        recPost(visit, subTreePtr->getRightChildPtr());
        ItemType temp = subTreePtr->getItem();
        visit(temp);
    }
}

template<typename ItemType, typename KeyType>
BinaryNode<ItemType>* BinarySearchTree<ItemType, KeyType>::copy(BinaryNode<ItemType>* optr)
{
    if(optr != nullptr)
    {
        BinaryNode<ItemType>* newNode = new BinaryNode<ItemType>(optr->getItem());
        newNode->setLeftChildPtr(copy(optr->getLeftChildPtr()));
        newNode->setRightChildPtr(copy(optr->getRightChildPtr()));
        return newNode;
    }
    return nullptr;
}

template<typename ItemType, typename KeyType>
BinaryNode<ItemType>* BinarySearchTree<ItemType, KeyType>::greatest(BinaryNode<ItemType>* ptr)
{
    if(ptr!=nullptr && ptr->getRightChildPtr()!=nullptr)
    {
        return greatest(ptr->getRightChildPtr());
    }
    if(ptr!=nullptr && ptr->getRightChildPtr()==nullptr)
    {
        return ptr;
    }
    return nullptr;
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//      PUBLIC METHODS BEGIN HERE
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

template<typename ItemType, typename KeyType>
BinarySearchTree<ItemType, KeyType>::BinarySearchTree() : rootPtr(nullptr) 
{
}

template<typename ItemType, typename KeyType>
BinarySearchTree<ItemType, KeyType>::~BinarySearchTree()
{
   this->destroyTree(rootPtr); // Call inherited method
}  // end destructor


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//      Public BinaryTreeInterface Methods Section - IMPLEMENT THESE
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

template<typename ItemType, typename KeyType>
void BinarySearchTree<ItemType, KeyType>::operator=(BinarySearchTree<ItemType, KeyType>& bst)
{
    this->rootPtr = copy(bst.rootPtr);
}

template<typename ItemType, typename KeyType>
bool BinarySearchTree<ItemType, KeyType>::add(const ItemType& newData)
{
    BinaryNode<ItemType>* newNode = new BinaryNode<ItemType>(newData);
    if(rootPtr == nullptr)
    {
        rootPtr = newNode;
        return true;
    }
    if(insertInorder(rootPtr, newNode) == nullptr)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

template<typename ItemType, typename KeyType>
bool BinarySearchTree<ItemType, KeyType>::remove(const KeyType& key)
{
    if(contains(key))
    {
        KeyType a = key;
        ItemType item = getEntry(a);
        rootPtr = recRemove(rootPtr, item);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

template<typename ItemType, typename KeyType>
ItemType BinarySearchTree<ItemType, KeyType>::getEntry(const KeyType& aKey) const throw(NotFoundException)
{
    BinaryNode<ItemType>* entry = findNode(rootPtr, aKey);
    if(entry != nullptr)
    {
        return entry->getItem();
    }
    throw(NotFoundException("Node with given key doesn't exist"));
}

template<typename ItemType, typename KeyType>
bool BinarySearchTree<ItemType, KeyType>::contains(const KeyType& aKey) const
{
    BinaryNode<ItemType>* entry = findNode(rootPtr, aKey);
    if(entry != nullptr)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//      Public Traversals Section - IMPLEMENT THESE
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

template<typename ItemType, typename KeyType>
void BinarySearchTree<ItemType, KeyType>::preorderTraverse(void visit(ItemType&)) const
{
    recPre(visit, rootPtr);
}

template<typename ItemType, typename KeyType>
void BinarySearchTree<ItemType, KeyType>::inorderTraverse(void visit(ItemType&)) const
{
    recIn(visit, rootPtr);
}

template<typename ItemType, typename KeyType>
void BinarySearchTree<ItemType, KeyType>::postorderTraverse(void visit(ItemType&)) const
{
    recPost(visit, rootPtr);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you actually provide a copy constructor for your class. In which case, the compiler automatically generates one that simply copies `rootPtr` over (also know as a "shallow copy"). You end up with two instances of `BinarySearchTree` both holding a pointer to the same data structure, and both thinking they own it. Whichever one is destroyed first will take the whole structure down with it. See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)

Comment: So what would a copy constructor look like? Something like this?: `BinarySearchTree<Itemtype, Keytype>::BinarySearchTree(BinarySearchTree<ItemType, KeyType>& bst) {*(this) = bst}`

Comment: Something like what?

Comment: edited my comment!

Comment: Yes, that looks like it should work.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thanks so much!